# How to get the best gaming experience with 3D projector?

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I've got a 3D projector, bought some DLP-link glasses, and finally got everything set up to run Black Ops 2 Zombies in 3D mode from a PC.  The effect looks OK standing still, but while looking around **the experience feels like having each eye pointing in a different direction** - extremely unnatural and very quickly sickening to the point I would much, much rather play with 2D display.

I am a little disappointed it's this bad, since I would never want to play in 3D with that experience, and it took a fair amount of effort getting all the equipment and configuring it correctly!  Is it something to do with the specific game?  Are other games better or at least different?  Are there some settings I ought to try changing or other setups that might work better?  For example I tried making sure V-sync was on, and tweaked the field of view a little, but it doesn't help enough to make me want to play.

Comment: This might be a good fit for ux.se.

Comment: Black Ops 2 might not have been ment to be played with a 3D projector.

Answer (score 1):

The game experience of CoD Black ops 2 is just 3 stars on [nvidia 3d vision](http://www.nvidia.ca/object/3d-vision-games.html), so don't expect too much from it. 
However you can try adjust the depth settings, it might help with the feel of looking to two different directions. 
[image]

Comment: There are in game Keyboard Shortcuts/hotkeys for this.. You'll want to use those.

You can also try iz3D driver